# AWS SDK not working in my SSIS package under a script task

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssis, aws-sdk

I've referenced the DLL in the script task and have no errors until I press OK on the Script Task Editor. Then I get "Scripts contained in the package have compilation error. Do you want to save changes?". I reference AWS SDK S3 and Core

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you post the error that you are facing?

Comment: I did. That's all I'm getting. No red lines in the script task. Just when I save, close out and press Ok, I get that error

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own issue. Basically the AWS SDK was not in the GAC. After I did that. My script task was able to save.